# python: find all keys with a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested

I have a dictionary like below:

```
mydict = {'a' : 'apple',
     'b' : 'bobb',
    'c' : {
         'd' : 'dog'
       },
      'e' : 'dog'
     }
```

Suppose I want to find all the keys with value '`dog`'In case of nesting, the keys should be separated by a dot.

So the output should be a list `['e', 'c.d']`

Now if I write below code in python 3, it only outputs '`e`'.

```
print(list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index('dog')])
```

How can I get the nested keys?

Comment: make a recursive `function x` that searches every val for `dog` and sends every val that is `dict` to `function x`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a recursion function like following:

```
def find_key(mydict, pre=tuple()):
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from find_key(value, pre=pre+(key,))
        elif value == 'dog':
            if pre:
                yield '.'.join(pre + (key,))
            else:
                yield key
```

test:

```
In [23]: list(find_key(mydict))
Out[23]: ['e', 'c.d']
In [26]: mydict = {'a' : 'apple',
     'b' : 'bobb',
    'c' : {
         'd' : 'dog'
       },
      'e' : 'dog',
     'k':{'f':{'c':{'x':'dog'}}}}

In [27]: 

In [27]: list(find_key(mydict))
Out[27]: ['k.f.c.x', 'e', 'c.d']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion (although @Kasramvd beat me to it, here is a non-generator version for good measure):

```
>>> def find_key(value, d, level=None, acc=None):
...     acc = acc if acc is not None else []
...     level = level if level is not None else []
...     for k,v in d.items():
...         if isinstance(v, dict):
...             find_key(value, v, level=[*level, k], acc=acc)
...         elif v == value:
...             acc.append('.'.join([*level,k]))
...     return acc
...
>>>
>>> find_key('dog', mydict)
['c.d', 'e']
```

And with Kasramvd's messier test-case:

```
>>> mydict = {'a' : 'apple',
...      'b' : 'bobb',
...     'c' : {
...          'd' : 'dog'
...        },
...       'e' : 'dog',
...      'k':{'f':{'c':{'x':'dog'}}}}
>>> find_key('dog', mydict)
['c.d', 'e', 'k.f.c.x']
```

Comment: *non-generator version for good measure*? Not efficient and Pythonic though! I'd liked to see a non-recursion solution for the sake of memory efficiency not a non-generator solution that makes it even worse!

Comment: @Kasramvd well, I had posted it before I saw you had already provided a solution, and perhaps I was too attached to it. I'm not sure an iterative solution would be necessary, honestly, if you are nesting more than 10 levels deep, you've got other problems

Answer (score 1):

You can also use recursion with a list comprehension:

```
mydict1 = {'a' : 'apple',
    'b' : 'bobb',
    'c' : {
       'd' : 'dog'
      },
     'e' : 'dog'
     }

mydict = {'a' : 'apple',
 'b' : 'bobb',
'c' : {
     'd' : 'dog'
   },
  'e' : 'dog',
 'k':{'f':{'c':{'x':'dog'}}}}

s = [mydict1, mydict]
def get_val(d, target='dog'):
  return reduce(lambda x, y:([x] if isinstance(x, str) else x)+([y] if isinstance(y, str) else y), list(filter(None, [a if b == target else "{}.{}".format(a, get_val(b)) if isinstance(b, dict) else None for a, b in d.items()])))


new_s = list(map(get_val, s))
```

Output:

```
[['c.d', 'e'], ['c.d', 'e', 'k.f.c.x']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
mydict = {'a' : 'apple',
     'b' : 'bobb',
    'c' : {
         'd' : 'dog'
       },
      'e' : 'dog',
     'k':{'f':{'c':{'x':'dog'}}},

      'p':{'r':{'h':{'m':{'n':{'o':{'a':{'b':{'t':{'z':{'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':{'e':{'f':{'g':'dog'}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}







          }

your_word='dog'

result = []

for key,value in mydict.items():
    if value==your_word:
        result.append(key)
    elif isinstance(value,dict):

        def recursive_approach(my_dict, nested_dict=key):

            for i, j in my_dict.items():
                if isinstance(j, dict):

                    nested_dict = "{}.{}".format(nested_dict, i)


                    return recursive_approach(j, nested_dict)
                else:
                    if nested_dict == '':

                        if j == your_word:
                            result.append(i)
                    else:
                        if j == your_word:
                            result.append("{}.{}".format(nested_dict, i))


        recursive_approach(value)





print(result)
```

output:

```
['p.r.h.m.n.o.a.b.t.z.a.b.c.d.e.f.g', 'k.f.c.x', 'e', 'c.d']
```