# Extract keys and values from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a nested dictionary in the form

```
'adipisci': {'foo': {'<UNK>': 2},
              'adipisci': {'<UNK>': 2},
              'non': {'adipisci': {'<UNK>': 2}}
              'est': {'<UNK>': 3},
              'tempora': {'<UNK>': 5}}
```

I need to generate

```
adipisci foo 2
adipisci adipisci 2
adipisci non adipisci 2
adipisci est 3
adipisci tempora 5
```

I have the following code but I am not getting expected results

```
def myprint(d,result):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k=='<UNK>':
           print(result)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result+=' '+k
            myprint(v,result)
        else:
            print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))
```

Comment: If `k=='<UNK>'` you need the value.  Here you're returning nothing.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd Yes. It marks the end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: find all keys with a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276165/python-find-all-keys-with-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of the parent keys as a path when making a recursive call, so that when you see the key `UNK` you can print the path along with the current value:

```
def myprint(d, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == '<UNK>':
            print(' '.join(path + [str(v)]))
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            myprint(v, path + [k])
```

so that `myprint(d)` outputs:

```
adipisci foo 2
adipisci adipisci 2
adipisci non adipisci 2
adipisci est 3
adipisci tempora 5
```

Note that if you're using Python 3.5 or later versions, you can use generic unpacking to print the items of `path`:

```
print(*path, v)
```

instead of `print(' '.join(path + [str(v)]))`.

Comment: @Phydeaux Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument .

Comment: error `can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

Comment: @Rohit I don't think you ran my example code correctly. Please run the demo here: https://repl.it/repls/MediumorchidWateryVerification